# Optimizing Gensim word mover's distance function for speed (wmdistance)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I am using `gensim` `wmdistance` for calculating similarity between a reference sentence and 1000 other sentences.

```
    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
     'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
    model.init_sims(replace=True)  

    reference_sentence = "it is a reference sentence"
    other_sentences = [1000 sentences]
    index = 0
    for sentence in other_sentences: 
      distance [index] = model.wmdistance(refrence_sentence, other_sentences)
      index = index + 1
```

According to `gensim` [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py), `model.wmdistance` returns the following:

```
emd(d1, d2, distance_matrix)
```

where

```
d1 =  # Compute nBOW representation of reference_setence.
d2 =  # Compute nBOW representation of other_sentence (one by one).
distance_matrix = see the source code as its a bit too much to paste it here.
```

This code is inefficient in two ways for my use case.

1) For the reference sentence, it is repeatedly calculating d1 (1000 times) for the distance function `emd(d1, d2, distance_matrix)`.

2) This distance function is called by multiple users from different points which repeat this whole process of `model.wmdistance(doc1, doc2)` for the same other_sentences and it is computationally expensive. For this 1000 comparisons, it takes around 7-8 seconds.

Therefore, I would like to isolate the two tasks. The final calculation of distance: `emd(d1, d2, distance_matrix)` and the preparation of these inputs: d1, d2, and distance matrix. As distance matrix depends on both so at least its input preparation should be isolated from the final matrix calculation.

My initial plan is to create three customized functions:

```
d1 = prepared1(reference_sentence)
d2 = prepared2(other_sentence)
distance_matrix inputs = prepare inputs
```

Is it possible to do this with this `gensim` function or should I just go my own customized version? Any ideas and solutions to deal with this problem in a better way?

Comment: did you code a customized solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to observe that this code could be refactored & optimized to avoid doing repetitive operations, especially in the common case where one reference/query doc is evaluated against a larger set of documents. (Any such improvements would also be a welcome contribution back to gensim.)

Simply preparing single documents outside the calculation might not offer a big savings; in each case, all word-to-word distances between the two docs must be calculated. It might make sense to precalculate a larger `distance_matrix` (to the extent that the relevant vocabulary & system memory allows) that includes all words needed for many pairwise WMD calculations.

(As tempting as it might be to precalculate all word-to-word distances, with a vocabulary of 3 million words like the `GoogleNews` vector-set, and mere 4-byte float distances, storing them all would take at least 18TB. So calculating distances for relevant words, on manageable batches of documents, may make more sense.)

A possible way to start would be to create a variant of `wmdistance()` that explicitly works on one document versus a set-of-documents, and can thus combine the creation of histograms/distance-matrixes for many comparisons at once.

For the common case of not needing *all* WMD values, but just wanting the top-N nearest results, there's an optimization described in the original WMD paper where another faster calculation (called there 'RWMD') can be used to deduce when there's no chance a document could be in the top-N results, and thus skip the full WMD calculation entirely for those docs.

Comment: Let me explore the option of RWMD then. Isn't WmdSimilarity(wmd_corpus, model, num_best=10) the same as RWMD then?

Comment: You'll have to check the paper for its definition of RWMD. Though there was some work started, I don't believe the gensim code yet performs that optimization. To find the 10 closest items, it calculates the WMD for *all* items, with no shortcuts/optimizations, then sorts to return just the 10 smallest-distances.

Comment: Ahh okay. I am going to modify it in a way where the word vectors and nbow vectors are calculated for a single document in separate function. It should save me a lot of time as I am comparing thousands of items with a single reference. I can start an issue as a feature request if you want it as wmdistance variant in gensim.